# Need assistance with SQL Query with error message Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, partitioning, cumulative-sum

I have two tables, and I would like to update the running balance of expenses by retrieving the allocation(budget) based on matching voteid

I'm using phpmyadmin mysql

- Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.6
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.6
- PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
- PHP version: 7.4.6
- Server type: MariaDB

This is my SQL statement so far

```
SELECT allocation 
FROM vote 
INNER JOIN expenditure ON vote.voteid = expenditure.voteid 
GROUP BY vote.voteid;

SET @csum = (SELECT allocation 
             FROM vote 
             INNER JOIN expenditure ON vote.voteid = expenditure.voteid 
             GROUP BY vote.voteid);

UPDATE expenditure 
SET balance = (@csum = @csum - expenses) OVER (partition BY voteid ORDER BY expenditureid) AS balance;
```

Error message :

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Table 1

```
| voteid | allocation |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | 50000      |
| 2      | 10000      |
| 3      | 34000      |
| 4      | 70000      |
```

Table 2

```
    | expenditureid | voteid | expenses |
    +---------------+--------+----------+
    | 1             | 2      | 300      |
    | 2             | 2      | 650      |
    | 3             | 4      | 900      |
    | 4             | 4      | 1200     |
    | 5             | 3      | 34000    |
```

Expected result

```
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| expenditureid | voteid | expenses | balance (running difference) | calculation (sample column should not be included)  |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|               |        |          |                              | 10000                                               |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1             | 2      | 300      | 9700                         | (10000-300)                                        |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2             | 2      | 650      | 9050                         | (9700-650)                                          |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|               |        |          |                              |                                                     |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|               |        |          |                              | 70000                                               |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 3             | 4      | 900      | 69100                        | (70000-900)                                         |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 4             | 4      | 1200     | 67900                        | (69100-1200)                                        |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|               |        |          |                              |                                                     |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|               |        |          |                              | 34000                                               |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 5             | 3      | 4000     | 30000                        | (34000-4000)                                        |
+---------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your sample data and calculation just make no sense.  I have no idea how `balance` is calculated.

Comment: I'm new to this forum so please bear with me. Are you viewing this on your phone or laptop because for some reason the tables are not displaying properly on mobile phone? So I could understand why you probably may not understand how balance is calculated. Are you seeing the tables clearly? I could explain better if you don't understand

Comment: . . I'm not sure that the forum has much to do with it.  You have a row with 300 as expenses, a balance of 7000 and an expression of 10,000 - 7,000.  The 7,000 is a total mystery.

Comment: Right you are totally correct. The calculation was an error on my part. I just updated it

Comment: But do you have a better understanding of the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

**total_allocation** is not a column according to what you've shown.

What you should do is:

```
SET @csum = (SELECT sum(vote.allocation) AS total_allocation 
             FROM vote 
             INNER JOIN expenditure ON vote.voteid = expenditure.voteid 
             GROUP BY vote.voteid);
```